# Sort pictures by tags with minizinc

Tags: sorting, optimization, constraint-programming, minizinc

I try to sort a list of photos with minizinc. I have a dzn file like this :

```
Données d'entrée
num_objects = 4;
num_words = [3, 2, 2, 2];
max_words = 3;
orientation = ["H", "V","V", "H"];
words = [|"cat", "beach", "sun",
>           |"selfie", "smile", "",
>           |"garden", "selfie", "",
>           |"garden", "cat", ""|];
```

I want to sort this list of pictures by maximizing the score. The score is the sum of the words in common between picture n and picture n+1.

For the moment i have this code. Before doing the sort that compares the photos, I have to sort this list by number of tags in descending order. Can someone help me ?

```
% Inclure le fichier dzn
include "Example.dzn";
include "globals.mzn";

% Nombre de photos
int: num_objects;
int: max_words;

% Informations relatives à chaque photo
array[1..num_objects] of int: num_words;
array[1..num_objects] of string: orientation;
array[1..num_objects, 1..max_words] of string: words;

% Variables de décision
array[1..num_objects] of var 1..num_objects: order;

% Contraintes
constraint alldifferent(order);  % Chaque photo doit être à une position unique
constraint order[1] = 1;  % La première photo est fixée à la position 1

% Conversion des mots clés en tableaux de booléens
array[1..num_objects, 1..max_words] of var bool: keyword_present;
constraint forall(i in 1..num_objects, j in 1..max_words)(
  keyword_present[i, j] = (words[i, j] != "")
);

% Calcul du totalScore
var int: totalScore = sum([sum([(keyword_present[order[i], j] /\ keyword_present[order[i+1], k]) | j in 1..num_words[order[i]], k in 1..num_words[order[i+1]]]) | i in 1..num_objects-1]);

% Maximiser le score
solve maximize totalScore;

% Affichage de la solution
output ["Ordre des photos: "] ++ [show(order)] ++ ["\n"];
output ["Score maximal: \(totalScore)"];
```

Thanks to those who will help me

Comment: What is your expected output for this model?